My Flutter project build fails with error MSB4019: The imported project "... Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    MSBuild version 17.11.2+c078802d4 for .NET Framework
    Build started 02/09/2024 18:50:07.

    Project "E:\myapp\flutterlearn\flutterlearn\build\windows\x64\CMakeFiles\3.29.5-msvc4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
    E:\myapp\flutterlearn\flutterlearn\build\windows\x64\CMakeFiles\3.29.5-msvc4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj(15,2): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\BuildCustomizations\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\BuildCustomizations\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
    Done Building Project "E:\myapp\flutterlearn\flutterlearn\build\windows\x64\CMakeFiles\3.29.5-msvc4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

    Build FAILED.

    "E:\myapp\flutterlearn\flutterlearn\build\windows\x64\CMakeFiles\3.29.5-msvc4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
      E:\myapp\flutterlearn\flutterlearn\build\windows\x64\CMakeFiles\3.29.5-msvc4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj(15,2): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\BuildCustomizations\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\BuildCustomizations\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

        0 Warning(s)
        1 Error(s)

    Time Elapsed 00:00:19.70

  Exit code: 1

Error: Unable to generate build files

Exited (1).

I installed visual studio and all tool as required but it seems the error still appears when I try to build or run an emulator

did you check if the file it mentions in the error message exist?

I was directed to reinstall visual studio with other tools but The error is still there

It doesn't and that's why am asking for help to make it exist

and what do you have closest to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\BuildCustomizations\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props? do you have C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio or C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022 at all?

I do have this      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022

and where the path differs? on v170?

I don't get, what do you mean

have you selected the device from the bottom right corner? I think "Windows" must be selected by default. You have to choose the device like android simulator

yes, emulators, desktop or web all just fail do you think there is a solution to it
